# Creating the users in the google domain (python)

Tags: json, python-3.x, google-apps-script, google-api, google-api-python-client

I am creating an application in which I am getting a Client_secret.json file, and in my application I'm trying to load that json file and get the credentials from it using the following code:

```
credentials=get_credentials(filename)
http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
service = discovery.build('admin', 'directory_v1', http=http)
userinfo = {'primaryEmail': primaryEmail,
    'name': { 'givenName':user },
    'password': password
}
service.users().insert(body = userinfo).execute()
```

It gives the following error:

> httpError 403 when requesting https
>   //www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users?alt=json returned
>   insufficient permission

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or am I missing something? I was wondering if the problem is in the json file which I'm creating?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Aman

Comment: What are you trying to do with this code? I don't think it's possible to create Google accounts programmatically outside of an Apps domain.

Comment: @duskwuff I am making a GUI which will take in csv file and create the users in google directory (Admin ---->users) so, that we dont have to manually create them. When I try creating the users, it always gives me permission issues. Not really sure how to resolve it.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can start by checking a few things:

1. If you're using a service account, be sure to enable the "wide domain delegation option" to allow a service account to access user data on behalf of your users and perform operations.
2. Check if the scope https //www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users is authorized for your client ID on your google admin console > Security > Advanced settings > Authentication > Manage API client access.
3. Check if the user that you're using to insert the new user have enough privileges a.k.a super admin privileges.
4. Check if the Admin SDK API is active on your project.

Keep in mind that just downloading the client_json and activating a API isn't enough to allow these types of operations. For certain APIs like Admin SDK, the user you're gonna use to consume those services need to have specific privileges.

Here's a few helpful links

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority
https://support.google.com/a/answer/162106?hl=en

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am not sure i am doing it right. So, I followed following steps to create the users in the google directory: Goto API and Services and since I will be using Admin SDk for creating the users, so I create OAuth credentials in there. Then I reference that file in here credentials=get_credentials(OAUTH_Client_Secret File) and then I http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
service = discovery.build('admin', 'directory_v1', http=http) service.users().insert(body=userinfo).execute()

Comment: @AmanKahlon if it throws an error, then by definition you are not doing it correctly. First make sure you can create the user via **Try This API** . Once that is working, then try using the same account via your Python code.

Comment: @tehhowch yes, I can create the user using that API

Comment: @AmanKahlon I think that for a admin sdk you must impersonate your credential with a service account with enough privileges to insert a new user in your domain, these links below show how to do it using python


https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/auth/service-accounts

Answer (score 0):

I would first check to make sure that you have the correct Admin privileges on the account that you are trying to use OAuth credentials on. I would try logging into the account and going to this reference page in the **Directory API** for `Users:insert`

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/insert

On the right hand side you should go to the **Try this API** section and see if that account has permissions to create new users.

Also another thing I noticed as well, is that you're not setting the required field `familyName` inside of the `name` field. `familyName` is a required property.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Added the family name since its is required field in there. I am not sure i am doing it right. So, I followed following steps to create the users in the google directory: Goto API and Services and since I will be using Admin SDk for creating the users, so I create OAuth credentials in there. Then I reference that file in here credentials=get_credentials(OAUTH_Client_Secret File) and then I http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http()) service = discovery.build('admin', 'directory_v1', http=http) service.users().insert(body=userinfo).execute() is it right?